# How to calculate correlation matrix with 2 RDD in Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 RDD as below:

col1: 3,4,3,2,3,5,7,6,5

col2: 1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0

Datatype is also Int.

I need to calculate correlation matrix, let me know how we can do with SparkRDD

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it'll solves your problem

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics
Statistics.corr(col1)
Statistics.corr(col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example, You can find the details for calculating correlation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html#correlations)

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD


val col1: RDD[Double] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(3,4,3,2,3,5,7,6,5))
val col2: RDD[Double] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0))

// compute the correlation using Pearson's method
val correlation: Double = Statistics.corr(col1, col2, "pearson")
println(s"Correlation is: $correlation")
```

Hope this helps!